# Laravel returns 404 on a edit route (Laravel 6.11.0)

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-6

I have created the following route.

```php
Route::resource('admin/products/', 'ProductsController')->middleware('auth');
```

I've used Artisan to create a controller with all the methods (index, create, edit, etc).

When I use the command *php artisan route:list* I get the following routes (among others):

`GET|HEAD  | admin/products/{}/edit | edit   | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@edit   | web,auth|`
`DELETE    | admin/products/{}      | destroy| App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@destroy| web,auth|`

Which is to be expected. But when I add `{{ route('edit', $product->id) }}` to the link href, the link is generated properly, but when I click on it, I get the 404 page. The same is when I use form to post to destroy (I've created a form with `action="{{ route('destroy', $product->id) }}"` and `@method('DELETE')` and I still get 404.

Any help where I should start looking for a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove trailing slash from your route resource name. Change `Route::resource('admin/products/', 'ProductsController')->middleware('auth');` to `Route::resource('admin/products', 'ProductsController')->middleware('auth');`

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by  Harven, the problem was that the resource route was not defined properly. After removing the backslash, everything started to work:

```
Route::resource('admin/products', 'ProductsController')->middleware('auth');
```

After this, the route list was filled properly, and the route name was also properly generated

`| GET|HEAD| admin/products/{product}/edit | products.edit | App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@edit | web,auth |`

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```php
GET|HEAD  | admin/products/{}/edit
```

the `{}` should be filled with a value, something like `{item}`

If in your controller `ProductsController@edit` method you have the code like

```php
public function edit(Request $request, Item $item){
}
```

the second argument `Item $item` should 1) exist, 2) should match the value you have in your route **{variable}**, so if you have `{item}` the variable in the method argument should be `item`, if it's `{something}` then it should be `public function edit(Request $request, Item $something);...`

> Note that Request $request, is not required in the method;

I'd like to add that, doing so `Item $item` will result in 404 if the item is not found, the item will be fetched based on the `getRouteKeyName()` method in that Item's Model, therefore if you have in your Item `model` something like

```php
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
```

The item will be fetched by the `slug` column from database. again, if you don't have that method used it will use the ID.

So to sum up, the `web` whould have `{some_value}` in there matching your controller's argument of that model `Product $some_value`, where `some_value` is by default the ID of the Product model unless you're defining the `getRouteKeyName()` method your `Products` Eloquent model

[Laravel Controllers Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)
Hope that solves it!

Comment: Thank you for your time, but the problem was solved by Harven's suggestion.